# Error on calling set function from the Same Class

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a set function

```
public function set energy(value:int):void
```

when I try to call this function from the same class using

```
energy(10); or this.energy(10)
```

I get an error:

```
Call to a possibly undefined method energy.
```

There are no variables declared as energy in the class. Any clues?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

its a [property setter](http://qwickthoughts.blogspot.com/2007/07/getset-in-actionscript-3-explained.html), so you call it with:

`this.energy = 10;`